# power bi dax, filter based on multiple relationships

Tags: powerbi, dax

tldr: I have two tables linked with two relationships, how do I calculate using both?

Hi, I am building a report on a fictional phone company. The data is stored in mongodb with the following format

```
User Account {

    _id : unique account ID
    other account details : [...] 
    yearly records : Array [ Yearly Record]
}

Yearly Record {

    year num : ex 2022
    monthly records : Array [Monthly Record]
}

Monthly Record {
    month num : ex 5 for may
    purchased minutes : minutes purchased this month
    daily records : Array [Daily Record]
}

Daily Record { 
    date : date
    consumed minutes : minutes used today
}
```

In this scenario, the minutes do not expire, each month you choose the amount you want to top up. The tables of interest are the monthly and daily tables. PowerBI fuses all user accounts in a single table. I'll omit some things but it looks like:

```
    Monthly Records

       _id      purchased minutes                   monthly records idx        yearly records idx
account id                    100       position in monthly record array              same principle

-----------------------------------------------

Daily Records
       _id      used minutes             date          daily records idx    monthly records idx        yearly records idx
account id                 5       2022-10-31                       ...                     ...                        ...
```

All tables are linked using _id in the modeling. For daily and monthly, the active relationship is the month idx.  But since the tables are in the db, the month idx repeat so the relationship is many to many.

I havent found a way to filter out only the monthly details for only one user. SO if I were to put id and monthly purchase in  a table, each user contains the reords of all users (see below)

```
Monthly Records

       _id      purchased minutes                   monthly records idx        yearly records idx
         1                    100                                     0                         0
         2                    200                                     0                         0

Table:

id      year    month   purchased min
 1      2022      jan             100
 1      2022      jan             200
 2      2022      jan             100
 2      2022      jan             200
```

The right months line up but the records are treated as duplicates (so if in feb 1 bought 300, we'd see feb 300 for both 1 anbd 2). I would almost need two active relationships on both the month idx and the id

How do I create a measure that is affected by both relationships? For instance if I chose id =1 and year + month = jan 2022 in slicers I should get only 100

Is this even possible in dax? I tried playing around with filter by id to no avail. In python there would be ways but then we deal with script visuals

My end goal is graphing minutes balance over time with

```
 measure = bought - consumed
```

we'd see spikes at beginnings of month and the nline slowly go down as muinutes are used

I know you cannot outright define two active relationships but are there ways to deal with data as such?